# DataGridView Deleting Exception on Refresh Data

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview

I have a method to refresh my `DataGridView` in windows application. this method works. but when I delete some row from Grid, an exception occurred and application closed.

This is Refresh function:

```
private void RefreshGrid()
{
    try
    {
        picbx_Next.Enabled = false;
        picbx_Previous.Enabled = false;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        people = context.People
            .Where(c => c.BranchPersons.FirstOrDefault().BranchId == _BranchId)
            .Select(c => new OrderingData
            {
                CellPhone = c.CellPhone,
                Id = c.Id,
                Firstname = c.FirstName,
                PersonDutyId = c.PersonDutyId,
                Surname = c.SurName
            })
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.PersonDutyId)
            .ToList();

        lst = new BindingList<OrderingData>(people);
        dgv_PeopleInBranch.DataSource = lst;

        picbx_Next.Enabled = true;
        picbx_Previous.Enabled = true;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And this is my delete function:

```
private void dgv_PeopleInBranch_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv_PeopleInBranch.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (ReadyForDelete)
        {
            Guid Id = new Guid(e.Row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
            DeleteBranchPerson(Id);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When Delete function successfully execute, I call `RefreshGrid()` method to load new data from database. But I've got exception in my `program.cs` file! Note that the refresh function works completely without any error at form load.

This is final Exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>      Parameter name: index

Where is my mistake and How can I found which control raised this exception and fix it?

Comment: Do you have events connected to the DataGridView? If so, put breakpoints in them to observe if one or more are called when you change the DataSource of the grid. It is possible that these events contains code that doesn't handle correctly the changing of the datasource

Comment: Yes. Event connected to the Grid and I step by step checking using break point for these methods. All of them successfully completed but finally I've got this exception. I don't know what method or control raised this error?

Comment: I was reading about calling `dgv_PeopleInBranch.EndEdit();` or `this.BindingContext[this.dgv_PeopleInBranch.DataSource].EndCurrentEdit();` before changing the DataSource.

Comment: Thanks Steve. First line doesn't change any things but second code raise this error :  `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataSource`

Comment: On which line you getting an error?

Comment: My problem is that you say :) I can't find which line has error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem where it is. When We use `UserDeletingRow` event, event argument was created that was contain the current deleting row.

When I called another function to delete current record form Database and the Grid datasource, event argument index changed to -1. Also I changed Data source of Grid on `RefreshGrid()` method. Therefore Grid rows completely changed and last row that in event arg parameter not available.

To solve this problem and prevent the occurrence of that exception, we need to cancel event arg parameter to relase that. I Change `UserDeletingRow` method like below and It's works!

```
if (ReadyForDelete)
{
    Guid Id = new Guid(e.Row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
    DeleteBranchPerson(Id);
    e.Cancel = true; // Set this to cancel event arg.
}
```

Thanks for all the experts who have helped me. :-)

Comment: As per MSDN [http://j.mp/13v66hC] e.Cancel is used to cancel the delete event and prevent the row from disappearing. -- 

Tried multiple options like resetting the data source or clearing the binding but nothing solve the issue. -- This way, may not be the best practice but do SOLVE the issue